# Update a Node object with Spring data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to update an existent Node in the db.
I could correctly create a node but can't update an existent one.

```
try (Transaction tx = template.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx()) {
    Node node = repository.findNodeUsingId("n1");
    if(node != null){
          //Modify some properties using setProperty 
          node.setProperty("name","P");

          //How should I do to save the modified node object?
    }else{
          //Create the node
          //This part works fine
          node = template.createNode();                       
          node.setProperty("name", "T");
    }
    tx.success();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to save the modified object.

Once setProperty has been called, your node property has been set in the current Transaction.

The only thing you are missing here is to close the Transaction, check this (from [Neo4j Javadoc](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/)) about `Transaction.close()`:

> Commits or marks this transaction for rollback, depending on whether
>   success() or failure() has been previously invoked. All
>   ResourceIterables that where returned from operations executed inside
>   this transaction will be automatically closed by this method. This
>   method comes from AutoCloseable so that a Transaction can participate
>   in try-with-resource statements. It will not throw any declared
>   exception. Invoking this method (which is unnecessary when in
>   try-with-resource statement) or finish() has the exact same effect.

Comment: My bad. I missed a tx.success() in one case in my code so the solution you propsed wasn't working for me.
Your solution is correct